# what is wrong with this code, there is return everywhere it should be. please help, im very frustrated

Tags: java

```
  class Number  {

  int number;
  int triangularNumber=1;

   public boolean istriangularNumber() {



    while(number<triangularNumber)
       {
       triangularNumber=triangularNumber+1;  }

    if ( number<triangularNumber)  {
    return false;  }

    else if( number>triangularNumber)  {
    return false;  }

    if ( number==triangularNumber) {

    return true;}

   }

    }   



     Number typed= new Number();

     typed.number= 3;





    System.out.println(typed.istriangularNumber());
  }
}
```

ERROR:

> Line: 29 missing return statement

the code should tell if the entered no. is triangular or not.

Comment: Your code formatting is completely unreadable.

Comment: please format your code , and you have not added return statements if all of if conditions are failed

Comment: Message its clear and you are missing the return type in the `line 29`.

Comment: Next to the flaws already mentioned, your code makes no sense

Comment: @JoakimDanielson possibly because OP doesn't know how, or even what formatting would be acceptable. I would format it myself, but that's not so easy from my phone.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it is not.

You have only covered the cases you were checking in your conditions.
But what will be the response if none of your conditions were met?

That is why you are receiving an error for given line 29.
You need to cover the return statement for a default case - if none of your conditions were met.

Comment: To me it seems that all possible paths are covered. It's just that compiler doesn't do such deep analysis. Could you provide an example, where none of the conditions is met?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj no, but the way the compiler evaluates reachability can't know that.

Comment: I know that. I was just commenting on your sentence: "But what will be the response if none of your conditions were met?" - this would never happen(ignoring the fact that it won't even compile).

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Yo weren't talking to me hehe. As per the part you referred to my question to the author of the topic - current issue as well is that it does not compile due to the MISSING RETURN STATEMENT (because not all of the paths are covered). That is the main and only reason why am I putting that question on the table in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

Your function says (with a bit of reformatting)

```
boolean istriangularNumber() {
    while(number<triangularNumber)
    {
        triangularNumber=triangularNumber+1;
    }

    if ( number<triangularNumber)  {
        return false;
    }

    else if( number>triangularNumber) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( number==triangularNumber) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This has an `if`, meaning there appears to be a way to hit the end of the function, without having a return statement.

Dropping the last `if` and returning true at that point will sort out this problem.
Logically you have covered the three possible cases, but the compiler can't tell that.

---

Just to make some observations, given the comments popping up.

Look at your code:

In the loop

```
while(number<triangularNumber)
```

you keep making `triangularNumber` bigger until this is no longer true.

You then check

```
if ( number<triangularNumber)
```

This can't happen, since you stay in the `while` loop until you `number` is no longer less than the mentioned `triangularNumber`.
So, we don't need that case. We can just see if the number is actually a triangularNumber:

```
boolean istriangularNumber() {
    while(number<triangularNumber)
    {
        triangularNumber=triangularNumber+1;
    }

    return number==triangularNumber; 
 }
```

Did you mean less than? or are you really trying to run up the triangle numbers from 1 until you hit the number, or overshoot? i.e.

```
    while(number>triangularNumber)
    {
        triangularNumber=triangularNumber+1;
    }
```

One bonus question: do you really mean

```
triangularNumber=triangularNumber+1;
```

in your loop? You start at 1, then set it to 1+1, i.e. 2, then 2+1 i.e. 3, then 3+1 i.e. 4. These appear to be the natural numbers.

Do you mean this?

```
triangularNumber += triangularNumber+1;
```

Comment: However, you could just replace the last 3 conditions with `return number == triangularNumber;`.

Comment: Additionally, that `while` doesn't make sense: while number is less than tN, increase tN. If entered, that will just loop until `tN == Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Agree - I was midway through adding suggestions while other answers happened.

Comment: And of course, you don't need to check if a number is triangular iteratively: just check if `number = 0.5 * n * (n+1)` has an integer solution.

Comment: We could turn this into a maths question instead. But I think there are several learning points in here. Not sure how useful they may be to the world in general, but the logically (semantic) possibilities versus syntax and parsing of code to check for returns on all paths might be worth making.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      class Number  {
        int number;
        int triangularNumber=1;
        public boolean istriangularNumber() {
            while(number<triangularNumber){
               triangularNumber=triangularNumber+1;
            }

            if ( number<triangularNumber)  {
                return false;
            }

            else if( number>triangularNumber)  {
                return false;  
            }

            return true;
        }
    }   
     Number typed= new Number();
     typed.number= 3;
     System.out.println(typed.istriangularNumber());
  }
```

Try this. And please format your code properly so it can be readable.

Comment: This adds nothing new to what has been already answered except for a completely unnecessary else at the end

Comment: @JoakimDanielson main goal was to show him to consider all the IFs and ELSEs. Else any developer can make this code concise.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    class Number {

        int number;
        int triangularNumber = 1;

        public boolean istriangularNumber() {

            while (number < triangularNumber) {
                triangularNumber = triangularNumber + 1;
            }

            if (number < triangularNumber) {
                return false;
            } else if (number > triangularNumber) {
                return false;
            }else {

                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    Number typed = new Number();
    typed.number = 3;
    System.out.println(typed.istriangularNumber());
}
```

}

Your own logic is right, but there is a problem with the writing.

Comment: This adds nothing new to what has been already answered except for a completely unnecessary else at the end